# How do I write message queue handling in an object-oriented way?

Tags: refactoring, messaging, oop

If you had to write code that takes messages from a message queue and updates a table in a database, how would you go about structuring it in a good oo way. How would you structure it? The messages is XML data, one node per row in the table. The rows in the table could be updated, deleted or inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with OO implementations of message queues you make the classes that represent the individual types of messages yourself. To the extent that the different message types that you expect to get are derivates of each other, this provides your class hierarchy for the messages.

With configuration based persistence frameworks you can just set up presistence for these classes directly.

Then there's one or more classes that listen to the message queue and just persist the messages, probably just one. It doesn't have to be more elaborate than that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you've provided enough information for a good answer.  What do the messages look like?  Do they vary in contents/type, or are they all just "messages"?  Do they interact with each other, or is this just a data format conversion?  One of the keys to OO development is to realize that the "find the nouns-n-verbs" game (which is as much as you've described) rarely leads to the best solution.  It certainly won't be the worst, but you'll end up with data aggregation and a bunch of procedural code.

Procedural code isn't bad, though.  Why does it need to be OO?  Does the problem itself require polymorphism and data hiding?  Is there any complex behavior that you are trying to model?  There's no shame in using a non-OO solution, when the problem is simple.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of building OO code when doing messaging or dealing with any kind of middleware is to hide the middleware APIs from your code and just deal with business logic.

e.g. see these examples

- [POJO Consuming](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/pojo-consuming.html) which is pretty much the use case you describe and
- [POJO Producing](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/pojo-producing.html) if ever you need to send messages to a message queue.

Then you just need to define what your *Data Transfer Objects* look like; how you want to encode things on the wire in XML / JSON / whatever.

The great thing about this approach is your code is now totally middleware agnostic - you could swap out your message queue and use a [database or JavaSpace or in-memory SEDA or files or any other communication protocol or middleware API](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/components.html).